# Guidance on producing multivariate Radar plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, radar-chart

I am currently attempting to make two different radar plots (see attached drawn representations).

Both plots use the same nested experimental design utilizing two independent variables: location and lithology, covering 36 experimental sites. Location has three levels (W,C,E) with each of the categories containing three lithologies (C,M,P).

Plot one is a representation of the distribution of altitude and orientation across sites with orientation being in degrees (0-360) and altitude being in meters.

Plot two will be used to represent the differing minerology of groups of site utilizing three minerals (A,B,C).

[Drawn depiction of radar plot 1 with four cardinal directions, colours representing climate location (independent variable 1) and shapes representing lithology (independent variable 2).  Circles represent altitude with larger distance from the center indicating higher altitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcvRb.png)

[The second radar plot uses the same independent variables: location (W,C,E) and lithology (C,M,P) with the red highlighted area representing the quantity of mineral A and yellow indicating mineral B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwQjM.png) .

If anyone has any pointers, packages or guides which could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit:  The second plot doesn't seem too difficult to make but the first is still causing issues.  I have partially solved using polar plots but am now having difficulty adjusting the aesthetics.

Data head:

`head(radar_plot_data)`

`climate  lithology     plot pos_lit  code altitude_m orientation_ao`

`1: Central Calcareous C.C.Pp.1      CC C.C.1       1150          150.8`

`2: Central Calcareous C.C.Pp.2      CC C.C.2        860           24.0`

`3: Central Calcareous C.C.Pp.3      CC C.C.3       1026           90.0`

`4: Central Calcareous C.C.Pp.4      CC C.C.4       1326           86.3`

`5: Central Calcareous C.C.Pp.5      CC C.C.5        966           87.5`

`6: Central Metapelite C.M.Pp.1      CM C.M.1        951           28.3`

Current code:

```
`ggplot(radar_plot_data, aes(x = orientation_ao)) +`
```

`geom_point(aes(x = orientation_ao, y = altitude_m,`
`shape = climate, color = lithology, stroke = 2.5)) +`
`coord_polar() +`
`scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360),`
`breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 45),`
`minor_breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 15))`

Comment: One additional note: I believe I can make plot two using the fmsb package but plot 1 is proving more difficult as, using the methof depicted here: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/beautiful-radar-chart-in-r-using-fmsb-and-ggplot-packages/     I would have to use 360 variables for the perimeter of the circle (one for each degree)

Comment: try the package ggradar.